# Chrome showing android developer site in Russian

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu-14.04

[image]Whenever I open a particular page on google Chrome for training section of developer.android.com, eg https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/index.html, the default language that gets shown is Russian which is then Translated to English. Is there a reason this is happening. It doesnt happen when I open the same page in Mozilla. Also, I checked my default language in Chrome is set to English. Also, this Russian to English translation happens only for this android developer site. Is this a problem? Is there a way to fix this?

Apologies if this is not the right place to ask this question, but would really appreciate if someone could give a few pointers, as to how to get this defaulted to English. Though, I dont think this is related to OS, but I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

EDIT:
As suggested I tried deleting my Browser and Cookie Data, also cleared my history from Chrome. But still issue seems to persist.[image: Attaching the image here for your reference].

Comment: This isnt happening with me , using ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Yeah, I think it is specific to me only. It doesnt happen on my work computer either. Only happens on my laptop. Don't know, and can't even guess, why this is happening. Though Google translate does come to rescue, but this should not happen in the first place.

Comment: Deleted your cookie data ?

Comment: yeah, I deleted the cookies, history etc. The issue still persists. I have added images for further clarity about what is happening.

Comment: Hi, Tried my edited answer??

Comment: Yeah, i did this. I also deleted the hosted app data and content licences...no change. I even restarted the browser to be sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a Chrome feature, so no cookies involved.

This is happening because someone once clicked, on "translate", when the notification "this page is in English, do you want to translate this to ...".

Simply click the icon in the URL bar where the notification pops out, and disabling the translation should fix it.

See this video for details; https://youtu.be/hYiHv-7oWOI

---

**Edit**

I misunderstood or misread the question; setting the language can be done using the dropdown at the bottom of the page, or by following this link;

https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/index.html?hl=en

The added `hl=en` requests English, and you should get a popup which asks you if you want to change the language.

Comment: The problem is that it is saying that the page language is Russian and asks me if I want to translate to English (or chhose other languages from dropdown)...i am wondering how can page language be Russian.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: After clicking on the url with params hl=en, this gave me a dialog which asked If I want to set English as my Default language. After Setting English in that dialog, all pages are now loading in English. So, this seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Please delete your browser history and cookies data.As mentioned in this website,This site uses cookies to store your preferences for site-specific language and display options.So it must be an issue with your saved cookies.

Please view in the bottom of this image.[image: Check it here.]

Also, there are language settings on the bottom of the website also.Check if you have Russian selected there. Here is the image.Look at the right bottom corner. [image: Check here]

Comment: Deleting browser history can never be the solution to such an issue.

Comment: @Koen. Whatever you suggested in your edited answer.I already mentioned it in my edited answer. And in 3rd image, you can see that.